# React Hooks Memorize Cost

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Does `React.useMemo()` have the cost to compare, like `shouldComponentUpdate()` in `React.PureComponent` ?

Is it bad to put variables changed often into `useMemo()` or `useCallback()`'s deps.

Thanks

Comment: Have you profiled it?

Comment: Not an answer per se, but worth looking at: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#performance-optimizations

Comment: Well all those scenarios are really about caching _expensive_ operations that don't update often (if at all). So if variables change often then it doesn't sound like these would be saving you much, if anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a µ-benchmark, `React.memo()` seems to be the fastest, with `PureComponent` in the middle and `useCallback()` consistently the slowest:

```js
class P extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <span onClick={() => this.props.n} />
  }
}
function C(props) {
  const c = React.useCallback(() => props.n, [props.n])
  return <span onClick={c} />
}
const M = React.memo(props => <span onClick={() => props.n} />)

const target = document.getElementById('target')
function test(o) {
  console.log('From fastest to slowest:')
  const entries = Object.entries(o)
  const results = new Map(entries.map(([name]) => [name, 0]))
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e3; i++) {
    for (let [name, X] of entries) {
      const start = performance.now()
      for (let j = 0; j < 1e2; j++) {
        ReactDOM.render(<X n={i} />, target)
      }
      const took = performance.now() - start
      results.set(name, results.get(name) + took)
    }
  }
  const sorted = Array.from(results).sort(([, a], [, b]) => a-b)
  for (let [name, t] of sorted) {
    console.log(name, t)
  }
}

test({PureComponent: P, useCallback: C, memo: M})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="target" hidden></div>
```